# Updating different Objects that have same properties

Tags: c#, object

In my Code, i've got three (or more...) different objects, that all have the same properties **(e.g. TrackingItemType, ReaderID etc)**.

They are derived from CounterBase (which does not have the Properties needed, but others).

Now i want to iterate through a Collection of those objects. In the Collection, all of the three objects can occur. Therefore, currently i've implemented the "**update**" for each object seperately.

> **Question:** How can I avoid that duplicate Code written? Is there any
>   pattern available to update the different objects with same
>   properties?!

THANKS!

Method of interest:

```
    private void UpdateTrackingCounters(Reading readingData, TrackingItemType trackingItemType, string trackingCounterType)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (CounterBase counter in this.TrackingCounters)
            {
                if (typeof(TrackingSimpleCounter).IsInstanceOfType(counter))
                {
                    TrackingSimpleCounter trackingCounter = (TrackingSimpleCounter)counter;

                    if (trackingCounter.TrackingCounterType == trackingCounterType)
                    {
                        if ((trackingCounter.ReaderID == 0
                            && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == null)
                            || (trackingCounter.ReaderID == 0
                                && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == trackingCounter.TrackingItemType)
                            || (trackingCounter.ReaderID == readingData.ReaderId
                                && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == null)
                            || (trackingCounter.ReaderID == readingData.ReaderId
                                && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == trackingCounter.TrackingItemType)
                            )
                        {
                            trackingCounter.IncreaseOne();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (typeof(TrackingIntervalBasedRollingCounter).IsInstanceOfType(counter))
                {
                    TrackingIntervalBasedRollingCounter trackingCounter = (TrackingIntervalBasedRollingCounter)counter;

                    if (trackingCounter.TrackingCounterType == trackingCounterType)
                    {
                        if ((trackingCounter.ReaderID == 0
                            && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == null)
                            || (trackingCounter.ReaderID == 0
                                && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == trackingCounter.TrackingItemType)
                            || (trackingCounter.ReaderID == readingData.ReaderId
                                && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == null)
                            || (trackingCounter.ReaderID == readingData.ReaderId
                                && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == trackingCounter.TrackingItemType)
                            )
                        {
                            trackingCounter.IncreaseOne();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (typeof(TrackingTriggerBasedRollingCounter).IsInstanceOfType(counter))
                {
                    TrackingTriggerBasedRollingCounter trackingCounter = (TrackingTriggerBasedRollingCounter)counter;

                    if (trackingCounter.TrackingCounterType == trackingCounterType)
                    {
                        if ((trackingCounter.ReaderID == 0
                            && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == null)
                            || (trackingCounter.ReaderID == 0
                                && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == trackingCounter.TrackingItemType)
                            || (trackingCounter.ReaderID == readingData.ReaderId
                                && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == null)
                            || (trackingCounter.ReaderID == readingData.ReaderId
                                && trackingCounter.TrackingItemType == trackingCounter.TrackingItemType)
                            )
                        {
                            trackingCounter.IncreaseOne();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Trace.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an interface that contains the properties and method you need:

```
interface ITrackable
{
    int ReaderID;
    string TrackingItemType;
    void IncreaseOne();
}
```

And add it to the declaration of each class that has them:

```
class TrackingSimpleCounter : CounterBase, ITrackable

class TrackingIntervalBasedRollingCounter: CounterBase, ITrackable

class TrackingTriggerBasedRollingCounter : CounterBase, ITrackable
```

If all the classes truly share those properties, you won't have to implement any of the interface, since it'll already be present.

Then all you need is

```
foreach (ITrackable counter in this.TrackingCounters)
{
    if ((counter.ReaderID == 0 && counter.TrackingItemType == null)
    || (counter.ReaderID == 0 && counter.TrackingItemType == counter.TrackingItemType)
    || (counter.ReaderID == readingData.ReaderId && counter.TrackingItemType == null)
    || (counter.ReaderID == readingData.ReaderId && counter.TrackingItemType == counter.TrackingItemType)
    )
    {
        counter.IncreaseOne();
    }
}
```

Although unless I misunderstand your logic all you truly need is:

```
foreach (ITrackable counter in this.TrackingCounters)
{
    if (counter.ReaderID == 0 || counter.ReaderID == readingData.ReaderID)
    {
        counter.IncreaseOne();
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use LINQ:

```
foreach (var counter in this.TrackingCounters.OfType<ITrackable>().Where(c => c.ReaderID == 0 || c.ReaderID = readingData.ReaderID))
{
    counter.IncreaseOne();
}
```

Comment: First that sounded like a great solution. Unfortunately, C# Interfaces may not contain fields / properties, just methods. //EDIT: Okay when adding getters / Setters its working. i'll try and give Feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

## Factorize

You can extract the common properties into one new common Object, and make both of your class have a reference property to that object.

This way, when you update this object, both of your original objects will have the most up-to-date values, without risk to forgot to update one of the properties.